# No delegate method called when new dialog created

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I have a list of dialogs which update as expected when a new message is posted to an existing dialog.

When someone sends me a new message in a new dialog (i.e. one that's not in the table view), nothing updates. No delegate method seems to be called, even though I have every `QBChatDelegate` and `QBChatServiceDelegate` method typed out and logged.

I have it set up so when I go to another view and back to the table view, it retrieves the dialogs manually and reloads the table view. I need this to update automatically though.

What am I missing?

Edit: Which delegate method should be triggered when a new dialog is created by someone other than the currently logged in user?

Edit: some code for a bit more context…

In my class I'm setting it to be the `QBChatDelegate` and the `QBChatServiceDelegate`;

`QBChat.instance.addDelegate(self)
self.chatService.addDelegate(self)`

I'm then logging the current user in to QuickBlox;

```
self.currentUser.blobID = qbUserID
self.currentUser.login = qbUsername
self.currentUser.password = qbPassword

self.services.logIn(with: self.currentUser, completion: { (success, errorMessage) in

    guard success, errorMessage == nil else {
        self.log.error("quickblox: \(errorMessage!)")
        return
    }

    self.chatService.connect(completionBlock: { (error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            self.log.error("chatService.connect: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    })

})
```

I then call every delegate method possible for both the `QBChatDelegate` and `QBChatServiceDelegate`;

```
// QMChatServiceDelegate

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didAddChatDialogToMemoryStorage chatDialog: QBChatDialog) {
    self.log.info()
    self.notifyOfNewMessage()
    self.delegate?.didCreateDialogs()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didAddChatDialogsToMemoryStorage chatDialogs: [QBChatDialog]) {
    self.log.info()
    self.notifyOfNewMessage()
    self.delegate?.didCreateDialogs()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didUpdateChatDialogInMemoryStorage chatDialog: QBChatDialog) {
    self.log.info()
    self.notifyOfNewMessage()
    self.delegate?.didUpdateDialogs([chatDialog])
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didUpdateChatDialogsInMemoryStorage dialogs: [QBChatDialog]) {
    self.log.info()
    self.notifyOfNewMessage()
    self.delegate?.didUpdateDialogs(dialogs)
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didDeleteChatDialogWithIDFromMemoryStorage chatDialogID: String) {
    self.log.info()
    self.notifyOfNewMessage()
    self.delegate?.didDeleteDialogs()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didAddMessageToMemoryStorage message: QBChatMessage, forDialogID dialogID: String) {
    self.log.info()
    self.notifyOfNewMessage()
    self.delegate?.didCreateMessages()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didAddMessagesToMemoryStorage messages: [QBChatMessage], forDialogID dialogID: String) {
    self.log.info()
    self.notifyOfNewMessage()
    self.delegate?.didCreateMessages()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didUpdate message: QBChatMessage, forDialogID dialogID: String) {
    self.log.info()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didUpdate messages: [QBChatMessage], forDialogID dialogID: String) {
    self.log.info()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didReceiveNotificationMessage message: QBChatMessage, createDialog dialog: QBChatDialog) {
    self.log.info()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didLoadMessagesFromCache messages: [QBChatMessage], forDialogID dialogID: String) {
    self.log.info()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didDeleteMessageFromMemoryStorage message: QBChatMessage, forDialogID dialogID: String) {
    self.log.info()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didDeleteMessagesFromMemoryStorage messages: [QBChatMessage], forDialogID dialogID: String) {
    self.log.info()
}

func chatService(_ chatService: QMChatService, didLoadChatDialogsFromCache dialogs: [QBChatDialog], withUsers dialogsUsersIDs: Set<NSNumber>) {
    self.log.info()
}

// QBChatDelegate

func chatDidReceive(_ message: QBChatMessage) {
    self.log.info()

}

func chatRoomDidReceive(_ message: QBChatMessage, fromDialogID dialogID: String) {
    self.log.info(message.text)

}
```

Edit: Removed un-relevant delegate methods and reference to tableview as it bears no relevance to the problem of *no delegate method being called when a new dialog has been created*

Comment: always include revelant code.. this is like diagnosing a patient from one sms in which he says he is feeling sick..

Comment: you have to reload your tableView with `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I'm not sure there's any code I can add that would help to be honest. As I said, I've implemented every delegate method of two separate objects. One of which _should_ catch a new dialog but none are.

Comment: well, in most of time the problem is in the code, because it does not really implement what the developer thinks it does. That's your case - you believe you implemented it correctly, but it behaves otherwise. Now how do you think we should be able to give you any advice, when you really present us only your assumptions, and what goes wrong about them? There are thousands of possible reasons that might cause this..

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Question updated with code

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of code, but very little relevant code - there is a long list of many delegate functions.. if they are called in one case and not in other, they most probably work as expected, and the problem is in wiring up the delegate pattern (so they are not needed to show here).. moreover, you mentioned something with the tableView, and I don't see any code that is connected to any tableView.. in these cases the relevant code is code that wires up delegates and viewControllers.. show us how you do that, in which callbacks (`viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, etc) you wire up stuff, etc..

Comment: @MilanNosáľ updated it once again - this time I've removed the reference to `UITableView` as it actually bears no relevance to the problem or question. I've also removed some extra delegate methods.

If you know which delegate method _should_ be called when a dialog is created, can you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you perform tableView.reloadData() whenever you send/receive the new message.

Make sure to update the data structure which is used to return number of rows in section for tableView.

Comment: I know when a new message in an _existing_ dialog is received but not when a new message in a new dialog - there's no delegate method called. If a delegate method was called that says "hey, I just got a new dialog and message" then I would reload the table view.